# Ubuntu server upgrade 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I have a production Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on DigitalOcean. I tried to upgrade it to 20.04 LTS, but after "sudo do-release-upgrade -d" I got this:

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent main InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/nginx/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:1 https://deb.goaccess.io bionic InRelease [1,629 B]
Fetched 1,629 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Sorry, no more upgrades for this system

There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system's
'i386' architecture.

Updates for Ubuntu 18.04 will continue until April 2023.


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Oct 12 06:01:54 2020) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Oct 12 06:02:04 2020) ===
```

What can be the reason for the upper problem?

Comment: Your message tells you "*There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system's 'i386' architecture*"   Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04 provided support for i386, but they're EOL now so only 18.04 LTS remains.  Your architecture appears to be i386 (32-bit).

Comment: You need to re-install to change architecture (ie. switch from *i386* to *amd64*).

Comment: Tnx. That's it.

Comment: What is the suggested method to upgrade from 18.04 LTS (32-bit) to 20.04 LTS (64-bit)? First, install fresh 20.04 LTS 64-bit. But how to simply restore all installed software and configuration :-)

Comment: Re-install is necessary; you can re-install desktops without loosing config, however you mentioned Server, and many server apps store config files in system directories which get wiped prior to re-install (desktops store their configs in user directories which aren't touched unless format is selected). Because you've said server, restoration of backup files will be necessary for many server configs.

Answer (score 2):

Your architecture appears to be i386 (32-bit); ie. your messages tell you

> *There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system's 'i386' architecture*

Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04 provided support for i386, but they're EOL now so only Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (& *flavors* remain.

You need to re-install to change architecture (ie. switch from *i386* to *amd64*).